# List Workflows start for item creator only

Tags: list, workflow, designer-workflow, error

I'm having issues with SharePoint workflows on a certain list. I've found only the creator of a list item is able to manually initiate a workflow for the item. To test I created a simple workflow that just wrote to the workflow history and I was unable to execute the workflow on any items I did not personally create and I get the following error:

> HTTP Unauthorized to
>   http://{server}/sites/{site}/_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid'8ce775a0-0a6f-4ce6-814c-bce8c5d4ca89')/Items(1156)
>   Correlation Id: 4942dd6e-5cc2-43dd-a15a-15b90b012c7d Instance Id:
>   6c479e00-ea55-4d6a-981e-fee0428a007d

I only experience this with a certain list and have been unable to recreate the issue with other lists using an identical workflow.

*Edit: I found out 2 settings were causing this to happen. 
First in Item-Level Permissions in Advanced List Settings I have "Create items and edit items that were created by the user" enabled. 
Second, under workflow settings I have "Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name" enabled. As the first was enabled by design I have disabled the workflow setting and the workflows now complete without issue. 
I can live without recording the workflow status but I would still like to know if there is a way to have this on for future use if needed.

Comment: There might be item level permissions maintained for the list on which you are working. Check the permissions on that list that you are having.

Comment: I have full control to the list and site collection admin permissions and it fails when I try to start a workflow as well as other accounts with just edit permissions I have tested with. Each account can only successfully start the workflow on items that account has create.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the advanced settings/versioning options.  If someone is only able to edit/view items he/she created, it may limit where a workflow can run.  By default, you need contribute rights to run a workflow on an item.  So these settings, which are list specific, may be the root cause.

Comment: I do have "Create items and edit items that were created by the user" enabled in advanced setting. But the accounts I've tested the workflow  with have either full control to the list or admin permissions (permissions that allow edit access to every items). Is it a known limitation that this setting will only allow workflows to be executed by the creator regardless of permissions that grant edit access to the full list?